# How do i make Circled numbers in UITextView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

Please Help..im not sure  were to begin

..How do i show numbers with circles around them in my  UITextView

like 1 2 3 4  .............but  each number inside a circle eg http://openclipart.org/people/gsagri04/GS_Numbers.svg

i was hopping to get numbers from an array and show them on screen ....but each number living  inside a circle like lotto numbers

@ the moment i only have  a An array [1,2,3,4],...A button .....and UItextView to show the final output

xcode 4.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your need correctly, you want to display following special characters in your textview:

① ② ③ ④ ⑤ ⑥ ⑦ ⑧ ⑨ ⑩ ⑪ ⑫ ⑬ ⑭ ⑮ ⑯ ⑰ ⑱ ⑲ ⑳

The easiest approach is to copy+paste these characters, and replace the numeric characters in the content string you need to display in the textview. You may write a NSString category method to handle this job, in sake of code reuse.

Comment: yea like that,writting a method might be bettwer than using a switch

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Chen's solution is pretty nifty, as you can change the characters on the go. But if you do not want to use the characters, you may use the following code to add circles to your textView.

```
UITextPosition *pos = textView.endOfDocument;// textView ~ UITextView

for (int i=0;i<words*2-1;i++){// *2 since UITextGranularityWord considers a whitespace to be a word, words = number of words in the textView.

UITextPosition *pos2 = [textView.tokenizer positionFromPosition:pos toBoundary:UITextGranularityWord inDirection:UITextLayoutDirectionLeft];
UITextRange *range = [textView textRangeFromPosition:pos toPosition:pos2];
CGRect resultFrame = [textView firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range ];

if (check whether word at this text position is a number){
     UIView* circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:resultFrame];
    circleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    circleView.layer.borderColor = <color of your choice, probably same as text color>;
     circleView.layer.borderWidth = <the width you want to set the border thickness to>;
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = <a float value that makes the rectangle look like a circle>;
    circleView .tag = 125;
    [textView circleView ];
}
pos = pos2;
```

}

The code should be placed in the UITextView delegate method textViewDidChange. And make sure you remove the circle view before all this code, hence the tag(125).